# Read Serial Data

Tags: c#, serial-port, readline

I am bashing my head with this.

I am writing a serial app for a machine that tests blood. It sends information on a line basis terminated with `\r\n`.

The issue is that every other time I run the machine it misses some lines, or its duplicating them. I stop and restart and the data then comes through fine.

Im using the DataReceived event:

```
try
{
    this.the = thePort.ReadLine();
}
catch (TimeoutException ex) {}
```

I am totally confused as to why sometimes it misses the first line which would be S1 to say the communication has started, and at the same time it will duplicate the data after this.

I can see this by appending each line read to a textbox.

Comment: Do you properly Dispose of the port after you're done using it each time?

Comment: Serial data is sent, you are not guaranteed to have the entire data in a single read, you have to continous read the data.  There are hundreds if not thousands of examples of reading serial data the correct way.  You should be putting all the bytes together not replacing the data every time data is recieved.

Answer (score 3):

You're getting a race condition due to your overwriting the this.the each time. The events are firing slightly out of sequence or too close together for your app to cope. Consider using a thread-safe method of squirreling away your data like adding it to a buffer or a StringBuilder with some concurrency protection around it.

Comment: i mean example of how to make it thread safe? i see what your saying

Comment: Try updating your console using an event for every line you read rather than using a single variable which gets overwritten. A simple test is to use Console.WriteLine to write out the thePort.ReadLine() output directly.

Comment: ok thanks i see what is happening. i see how im replacing the content of the variable and sometimes the data is coming in too quick...but why does the data come quicker some times than others? surely it should just be the same rate every time..

Comment: Don't rely on asynchronous events being in a strict time order or regularity. The comms themselves may fluctuate, the Windows message loop may be on a tea break etc. A lot of moving parts.

Comment: I like the idea of using a buffer(stringbuilder or bytes) with concurrency.  If you are going to use the event handler change the readline to readexisting so the handler is not blocked.